# Scenekit - Soften physicsBody

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, scnnode

Is there a way I can "soften" a SCNNode with a physicsBody?

Right now, my nodes react to collisions between them as if they are made out of metal. I want their collisions to be more like pillows.

Setting the restitution ("bounciness") to 0 doesn't work, and I cannot find anything else that does this.

Answer (score 0):

Scenekit currently does not support Softbody.
Currently only Staticbody, Dynamic body and Kinematic Body can be used.
But you can deform the shape to fake the visualisation.

Comment: Too bad. Thanks for the answer max9xs